# Access Vue store inside service

Tags: vue.js

I'm a bit new to Vue and am trying to put my logic into the store so I can use it in several components throughout my app.  I've created a `leads.module.js` which calls my `leads.service.js` file.

```js
    import LeadsService from "../../services/leads.service";

    const state =  {
      leadsOverTime: {}
    }

    const actions = {
      async leadsOverTime({ commit }, group_by = '') {

        const response = await LeadsService.leadsOverTime(group_by);
        commit('leadsOverTime', response)
        return true

      },
    };

    const mutations = {
      leadsOverTime(state, data) {
        state.leadsOverTime = data;
      },
    };

    export const leads = {
      namespaced: true,
      state,
      actions,
      mutations,
    }
```

This file is imported by my root store which contains the state values I need in my service:

```js
    const state = {
        startDate        : moment().startOf('year').format(),
        endDate          : moment().format(),
        selectedLocations: [],

    }

    export default new Vuex.Store({
        modules: {
          leads: leads
        },
        state,
        strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
    })
```

Finally, my service makes the API call using these state variables:

```js
    import axios from "../axios";
    import {store} from "../store/store"

    const LeadsService = {
      leadsOverTime: async function(group_by = '') {
        await axios.get(
          `/dashboards/potential_clients.json?
            &start_date=${ store.state.startDate }
            &end_date=${ store.state.endDate }
            &location_ids=${ this.selectedLocations }
            &compare=year
            &group_by=${group_by}`)
          .then( response => {
            return response
          })
          .catch( error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
    };

    export default LeadsService
    export { LeadsService }
```

I thought this would work but I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

How else am I supposed to access these variables within the service?  The root store is imported in my `main.js` file which should get loaded before my service is called from within my component.  What am I missing?  Possibly worth noting that in my logs I see: `"export 'store' was not found in '../store/store'`.

Comment: `import store` instead of `import { store }`

Comment: smh.  Thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue with the code. Probably the importing of the `store` making the issue. If you're exporting your `store` as `const`, then you can import it like

```
// your store file
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      // your modules
    },
});

// importing store to other files
import {store} from "../store/store"
```

Otherwise you can simply import like

```
import store from "../store/store"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state is unknown because of the following declaration:

```js
import { store } from './store'
```

Originally, Vue recommends not to use the curly braces, but it prevents you from having state issues.

Answer (score -1):

No need to import the entire store. U can pass the necessary variables in the call "leadsOverTime" using context.

State variables cannot be accessed directly in actions, So use context to access the state variables.

Also to commit a mutation u can call like "context.commit"

Correct me If am wrong I am new to vue

```
const actions = {
  async leadsOverTime( context , group_by = '') {
    const response = await LeadsService.leadsOverTime(group_by,context.state);
    context.commit('leadsOverTime', response)
    return true
  },
};
```